# What score do you need to earn 3 stars in level 1c of Dr. Mario World?

Tags: dr-mario-world

How many points do you need to obtain in level 1c of the Dr. Mario World to earn three stars for that level?
Level 1c is located in Area 2 of World 1 as is referred to as a challenge stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these playthroughs of the level, it's somewhere between [29,347](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PG0_Xs2NpYs) and [35,836](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fheAS6JENwI). An estimated guess from judging the bar in the first video is 31,000.

EDIT: Updates to the app have raised the score requirement so that this answer is no longer accurate. [See this answer for a more up-to-date estimate.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/358248)

Comment: The time limit increase from 90 to 120 seconds in said update is probably why the score requirement increased as well.  I don't know which update is responsible for the increase but I know I've always had 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It must depend on additional criteria because I've gotten over 38000 but still get awarded only 2 stars.

[image: Over 38000]

Update

I achieved 3 stars at 45,911 using Goomba, Thwomp, and a 10% bonus (star) with 32 seconds remaining at clear.

[image: 45,911 points]

Comment: Interesting. Do you remember how much time you had left and/or what characters you used, and what version Dr Mario World? The video link I posted had 21 sec left, with Goomba adding points.Not sure what version the video link was using, but that was posted on Jul 11. The required score for 3 stars may also have been increased in a recent update, which would render my answer outdated.

Comment: I don't recall fur sure, but I believe goombas and... something else? I've since beat it again with over 40k points and more than 30 seconds remaining. Still only 2 stars. It's seeming impossible in the current configuration.

Comment: Did you have a look at the bar when you got 3-stars? You can use that to estimate the required score. My impression based on what you've posted is that it only depends on score, but the score requirement has been raised to be somewhere from 40k to 45k.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how you would go about estimating using the bar. In my experience, you only get three stars even the bar is completely full. I managed to beat it again with a score of 47,141. I had a base score of 19,100 and got 400 bonus from Thwomp, 191 from Goomba, and 27,450 for leaving 36 seconds on the clock. I tried to get a screenshot before the bar filled, but it filled too fast.

Comment: It moves fast. I find you have to record the footage and then rewind to try to estimate based on the bar, and that requires you to be able to record. The 3rd star should start appearing when the bar correlates with the required score. I rewinded the vidoes multiple times when using their bars to guide my estimation in my answer. At this stage, my assmumption is that the only critiera is still the score, but the required score has increased since this question was asked.